# Remove default description of Feature element

Tags: wix, wix3.8

Anyone know how to get rid of default description from the Feature element? Even if you set your description via Description attribute, this text still wouldn't go away..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a description you can author for the feature. (The description is above the red box, blank in your case.) It's a standard MSI disk-costing control. There's no way to suppress that in the default WixUI dialog set. You'd have to create a custom set and remove the ItemSize control.